# Add extra tick where vertical line crosses x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
dat = data.frame(val = 1:20, qtr = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = 20, by = '3 months')))

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = qtr, y = val)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.yearqtr(as.Date('2003-04-01')))
```

I want to add one extra tick in x-axis where my vertical line crosses the x-axis. The corresponding tick label will also be manual i.e. `'Sep : 2003-04-01'`. Is there any function available in `ggplot` to achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your bespoke date breaks as a separate vector.
And the labels as a matching text vector including the bespoke text for the x intercept tick.
Adjustments to the axis text for legibility.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

intercept_date <- as.yearqtr(as.Date('2003-04-01'))

x_breaks <- c(as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = 5, by = '12 months')), intercept_date)
x_labels <- c(as.character(as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = 5, by = '12 months'))), "Sep : 2003-04-01")

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = qtr, y = val)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = intercept_date)+
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = x_breaks,
                     labels = x_labels)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

- Option 2

In response to comment: intercept breaks and labels defined within `scale_x_yearqtr`:

```r
ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = qtr, y = val)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.yearqtr(as.Date('2003-04-01')))+
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = c(as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = 5, by = '12 months')), as.yearqtr(as.Date('2003-04-01'))),
                  labels = c(as.character(as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = 5, by = '12 months'))), "Sep : 2003-04-01"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is it possible to define `intercept_date , x_breaks , x_labels ` directly within the layer of `scale_x_yearqtr ` not outside of it, because they are used only by this layer except `intercept_date `?

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I think you are looking for; let me know if this is so.